# brew update ERROR when installing php54

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am a OSX user, recently I want to update my homebrew but continuing error like following
[image]

Is there anyone face such problem too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the presence of `/usr/local/var/homebrew/locks/update`, it seems that another homebrew update is in progress. I would start by running `brew doctor` and follow any instructions there. If that doesn't help, I would delete the lock file and and try to update again.

Comment: THX for your answer, I have start debug with brew doctor step by step

Comment: Besides.do you know how to solve the following problem and what does it mean?     
                                                                                                                 Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
Consider setting the PATH for example like so
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

Comment: I have had that happen to me once. I added it to my PATH in my `~/.zshrc`. I checked up on it weeks or months later (`echo $PATH`), and `/usr/local/sbin` was listed twice, so I removed it from my `~/.zshrc` again. So, I'm not really sure what happened...